# Javascript date to string (format hh:mm)

Tags: javascript

How can I convert a date object to the format `hh:mm` in JavaScript?

I have tested with:

```
const timeOptions = {
  hour: "2-digit",
  minute: "2-digit",
};

date.toLocaleTimeString(undefined, timeOptions)
```

But on Android devices I get `03:10:22`. On the other hand, I get the expected result on iOS devices `03:10`

Any ideas how I can get a consistent result that is device independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```js
let date = new Date();
let splitted = date.toLocaleString().split(' ')[1].split(':').splice(0, 2);
let result = splitted.join(':');
console.log(result);
```